# How to use inject String using injectable and get_it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 @LazySingleton()
 @ChopperApi(baseUrl:"/api")
 abstract class ChatApiService extends ChopperService { 
   
  @Post(path: "/logout")
  Future<Response> logout(
  @Body() Map<String, dynamic> body,);
  
  @factoryMethod
  static ChatApiService create(String accessToken){
   final client = ChopperClient(
    baseUrl: 'localhost:8000',
    services: [_$ChatApiService()],
    converter: JsonConverter(),
    client: http.IOClient(
     HttpClient()..connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 60),
    ),
    interceptors: [
     HeadersInterceptor({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':'Bearer $accessToken'
    }),
    HttpLoggingInterceptor()
   ]
 );
return _$ChatApiService(client);
}
}
```

the messange when running build runner says that the factoryMethod depends on String which is not injectable...
so how would you inject String

Comment: The question is where do you want to inject or more precisely, where did you try injecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can inject primitive or third party types using a module

```
@module
abstract class RegisterModule{
//register the string as a named type
 @Named('accessToken')
 String get accessToken => "myAccessToken";
}
```

now in your factory method or constructor annotated your injectable string with @named

```
 @factoryMethod
  static ChatApiService create(@Named('accessToken') String accessToken){}
```